# ms-scroll-snap-points not working in Windows Phone

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, windows-phone-8.1

It seems that `-ms-scroll-snap-points-x` is not working in Windows Phone 8.1 Update 1 (IE11 Mobile) while the same thing can run properly in Windows 8.1 Update 1 (IE11 Desktop and Modern)

You can test it yourself, or see [this example](http://codepen.io/foleyatwork/full/ylwoz/). (the background is not important for me. I just want this scrolling behavior which is in front)

It's the example from [this tutorial (The JavaScript Behind Touch-Friendly Sliders)](http://css-tricks.com/the-javascript-behind-touch-friendly-sliders/). It creates this effect using `-ms-scroll-snap-points-x` property for IE, and with some touch events for others.

Creating this effect using touch events is not an option, since they are terribly slow in Windows Phone.

So, is there any workaround to *simulate* the effect of `-ms-scroll-snap-points-x` in Windows Phone?

Or in general, is there any way to achieve the effect in the example and the tutorial to Windows Phone?

Update: I'm using PhoneGap, if it matters.